# ADODB Getting the column count

Tags: php, sql, mysql, adodb

I was reading through our code base at my company and I saw something that seemed like it could be done better.

```
$dbRow = $dbh->Execute("SELECT * FROM database.table LIMIT 1");
$tableColumnCount = $dbRow->_numOfFields;
```

Is this the only way to get a column count using ADODB? It just seems silly to have to execute a query so you can ask the question.

Comment: Does you OLE DB provider MySQL support ADODB's OpenSchema method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
   AND table_schema = 'your_database_name'
```

That said, you might want to run the `FLUSH TABLES` command prior to for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to reflect existing tables and columns [because the data is cached](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way, you'll have to end up hitting the database unless your program can magically know the schema of the table.  If LIMIT 0 is legal in MySQL then this would be slightly more efficient - as I expect would replacing LIMIT 1 with WHERE 1 = 0.

Comment: I just think executing the query to get the column count kind of looks ugly. I was hoping their API would expose a call for this.

Comment: If you want the count of columns it's not too bad, I suppose.  I agree - it is a little ugly.  A point well made though, Stevebot.

Answer (score 1):

[MetaColumns or MetaColumnNames](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#metacolumns) should give you this information